# Distributed pub/sub with single consumer per message type

Tags: node.js, redis, distributed-computing, publish-subscribe

I have no clue if it's better to ask this here, or over on Programmers.SE, so if I have this wrong, please migrate.

First, a bit about what I'm trying to implement. I have a node.js application that takes messages from one source (a socket.io client), and then does processing on the message, which might result in zero or more messages back out, either to the sender, or other clients within that group.

For the processing, I would like to essentially just shove the message into a queue, then it works its way through various message processors that might kick off their own items, and eventually, the bit running socket.io is informed "Hey, send this message back"

As a concrete example, say a user signs into the service, that sign in message is then placed in the queue, where the authorization processor gets it, does it's thing, then places a message back in the queue saying the client's been authorized. This goes back to the socket.io socket that is connected to the client, along with other clients that might be interested. It can also go to other subsystems that might want to do more processing on authorization (looking up user info, sending more info to the client based on their data, etc).

If I wanted strong coupling, this would be easy, but I tried that before, and it just goes to a mess of spaghetti code that's very fragile, and I would like to avoid that. Another wrench in the setup is this should be cluster-able, which is where the real problem comes in. There might be more than one, say, authorization processor running. But the authorization message should be processed only once.

So, in short, I'm looking for a pattern/technique that will allow me to, essentially, have multiple "groups" of subscribers for a message, and the message will be processed only once per group.

I thought about maybe having each instance of a processor generate a unique name that would be used as a list in Reids. This name would then be registered with some sort of dispatch handler, and placed into a set for that group of subscribers. Then when a message arrives, the dispatch pulls a random member out of that set, and places it into that list. While it seems like this would work, it seems somewhat over-complicated and fragile.

The core problem is I've never designed a system like this, so I'm not even sure the proper terms to use or look up. If anyone can point me in the right direction for this, I would be most appreciative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up wrapping around the redis publish/subscribe functions a bit to do this. Each type of message processor gets a "group name", and there can be multiple instances of the processor within that group (so multiple instances of the program can run for clustering).

When publishing a message, I generate an incremental ID, then store the message in a string key with that ID, then publish the message ID.

On the receiving end, the first thing the subscriber does is attempt to add the message ID it just got from the publisher into a set of received messages for that group with `sadd`. If `sadd` returns `0`, the message has already been grabbed by another instance, and it just returns. If it returns `1`, the full message is pulled out of the string key and sent to the listener.

Of course, this relies on redis being single threaded, which I imagine will continue to be the case.

Answer (score 2):

I think what your describing is similar to https://www.getbridge.com/ service. I it but ended up writing my own based on zeromq, it allows you to register services, req ->  <- rec and channels which are pub / sub workers.

As for the design, I used a client -> broker -> services & channels which are all plug and play using auto discovery, you have the services register their schema with the brokers who open a tcp connection so that brokers on other servers can communicate with that broker groups services. Then internal services and clients connect via unix sockets or ipc channels which ever is preferred.

Answer (score 1):

What you might be looking for is an AMQP protocol implementation,where you can have queue get custom exchanges,and implement a pub-sub model.

[RabbitMQ - a popular amqp protocol implementation with lots of libraries](http://rabbitmq.com)

it also has node.js library